# Why are sheet Filter Views not updating for new rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a sheet with two filter views, which apply filter on one column and sort on another. The sheet is populated from the API nightly - it has all worked great but today I noticed things in the wrong views.

[image]

First issue - *Labels* column is filtered on containing "CPA" but you can see the one right under the popup is "CVP,feature".

[image]

Second issue... Priority is sorted on value but the two new ones at the bottom are not being counted here.

I've tried switching filter views, refreshing the page in my browser, even closing and reopening the document, but nothing. What is wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

Apparently in Google Sheets, when you turn on the filter (say on the first row) and you don't create a named filter view, that filter on the first row is still set with a range that only goes to the maximum number of rows that you have set up at the moment you turn on filters.  If you add rows (not data to existing rows, but physical rows) to the spreadsheet, the filter will not read them.

In order to fix this, the user has to "Turn off filter" and then "Turn on filter" to reset the range.

Comment: This is works for me and should be marked as the correct answer. One small correction to it though. It is now "Create a filter" rather than "Turn on filter".

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheet's Filter Views only work on the range specified. This range does not update upon the adding of rows or columns.

The second issue, the number not being sorted, is because of the first one. Those cells are not in the range of the Filter View.

Comment: I don't think I set the range when I created the filter views... The sheet is repopulated each night by a script. But if you show me how to reset this I'll be corrected

Comment: The only way to update the range of the fitler view programatically is by using the Sheets v4 REST API You can find exactly how to do that in the documentation. The range of a filter view is automatically set to whatever range was highlighted when it was created. Open up a filter view, the top should say Name: Filter 1 to left of that is the range, you can type of this to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the range defined - it is highlighted in green line

I just ran into this problem myself, and this is what I did to solve it (2 options)

## Option 1 - Simply update the range

The range is specified in the bar on the top, above the columns. Just update it.

[image]

## Option 2 - Select option in menu to update the range

If you cannot find the range, go to the menu

`Selected Data -> Filter Views -> Filter view options -> Update Range`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the filter view, then create a selection encompassing all columns and all rows (usually, you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> twice). *Then* update the range. That should suffice.